# Alex and Eric are two of the 8 students competing for a certain 5 person chess team.?

Tags: combinatorics

If Alex and Eric must make the chess team,in how many different ways can the chess team be populated. 
Answer is 20,Anybody Elaborate plz...

Comment: Will you plz explain it more.

Comment: First mention if you have tried anything and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: I have tried it and getting answer by 6C3,but unable to understand the concept..

Comment: Out of the remaining $8-2$ students, choose $5-2$ students: $\binom{8-2}{5-2}=\binom63=20$.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have answered the question yourself in the comments...

We need to choose $5$ people for the chess team. We must have Alex and Eric (and there is only one way that we can take Alex and Eric), so we need to choose $3$ more members from the remaining $6$. Thus, there are $\displaystyle{6 \choose 3}=20$ ways that the chess team can be populated.